# Selenium switch to the wrong iframe when closing another one

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

I'm using Selenium to perform some test. My problem is that i've 4 nested iframes and when i close one, Selenium switch to the wrong one.

To help you to understand my problem i have a little sketch :
[image]

So my first frame (the black one) open a nested frame (the grey one) who open another one (the orange one) and again, open another one (the white one). The problem is : when i close the white frame, Selenium switch to the grey one but is should normaly switch to the orange one.

When a frame close, i use `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();`. It worked fine every time but in that case, it doesn't work and i can't find the issue.

I've tried some test code as

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe")).size() > 0) {
     driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe")).size() - 1);
}
```

but it doesn't work too.

If anyone have an idea or encounter the same problem, i'll be glad to try your answer.

Edit : Here is my stacktrace, so before performing some action, i switch to the wanted frame :

```
frameLocator = By.xpath: //*[@id='greyWindow']
___Before switch and before execute___ 
CurrentFrame =: title=defaultWindow

___After switch and before execute___ 
CurrentFrame = <IFRAME src=grey id=greyWindow>

frameLocator = By.xpath: //*[@class='redWindow']
___Before switch and before execute___ 
CurrentFrame = <IFRAME src=grey id=greyWindow>

___After switch and before execute___
CurrentFrame = <IFRAME src=red class=redWindow>

frameLocator = By.xpath: //iframe[contains(@src,'whiteWindow')]
___Before switch and before execute___ 
CurrentFrame = <IFRAME src=red class=redWindow>

___After switch and before execute___ 
CurrentFrame = <IFRAME src=whiteWindow>

Frame currently available : [[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on LINUX (5c408ef997226a10c864cbeec0a2472d)] 
-> tag name: iframe] | frame.getAttribute("innerHTML") = // Nothing appear
Frame currently available : [[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on LINUX (5c408ef997226a10c864cbeec0a2472d)]
-> tag name: iframe] | frame.getAttribute("innerHTML") = // Nothing appear

//Here i just put some value and close the frame as every frame before

___Before switch and after execute___ 
CurrentFrame = title=defaultWindow

___After switch and after execute___ 
CurrentFrame = title=defaultWindow
```

Then I got nullPointerException because the current frame isn't the red window but the default window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the idea of @Shivam Mishra, i've created this method :

```
public static void switchToTheParentFrame(final WebDriver driver) {
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        iframeList.remove(iframeList.size() - 1);
        final Iterator<By> itr = iframeList.iterator();
        if (!iframeList.isEmpty()) {
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                final WebElement frame = driver.findElement(itr.next());
                try {
                    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
                } catch (final WebDriverException wde) {
                    LOG.error("Error while switching to the frame : " + frame.toString(), wde);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`iFrameList` is a global variable that i init at every test with an empty list.

Then i can continue my test without crashing. So i force Selenium to come back to the good parent frame. I hope this will help somebody !

Answer (score 1):

Why not switch to the frame by name or some other selector?

```
driver.switchTo().frame("name_or_id");
```

Or you could try saving the frame in a WebElement variable and then switch to that. Ex:

```
WebElement iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.id("name"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you need to access the iframes from a list after verifying it to be the correct one, you could try:

```
List <WebElement> all_iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
for(WebElement iframe : all_iframes)
{
  if(iframe.getAttribute("name") == "your required name")
  { 
    //do some stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: This options could be good but i should implement a list, because if Selenium worked well, it should switch automaticaly to the good frame. With a list i must verify if my current frame is the good one, if not, i must switch to the good one.

Comment: I did with a list of current frame available but as you can see in my edit only 2 frames are available (don't know why only 2 because 3 are currently showed) and they are not the one that i want. Something is strange here @Shivam

Comment: Judging by your answer, you are able to get the frame now right? Is their still any problem?

Comment: I've answered my own question using your idea. In my mind Selenium act strangely, but it's working right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Or use : `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();`

Comment: @Samix : let me know if you face any issue

Comment: the driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); switch my frame to the window() not to the white frame

Comment: @Samix : use driver.switchTo().parentFrame();

Comment: @Pritam He has already mentioned driver.switchTo().parentFrame() doesn't work for him in the question.