# Wait for script to be done before switching to a frame in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium

I'm trying to switch to an iframe, but, i must wait for a script to be done before switching.

As i asked here : [Selenium switch to the wrong iframe when closing another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904772/selenium-switch-to-the-wrong-iframe-when-closing-another-one) and answered it, i can force the switch to the parent frame and use the same idea to switch to a frame with or without any script.

The problem is that forcing the switch isn't a good way to do it. It's similar as using a `Thread.sleep(500)` because i know that it take approximately 500ms to execute the script.

So i'm trying to wait for jQuery and JavaScript to be done by using :

```
// Wait for JS 
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> waitForJSToLoad() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(final WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
        }
    };
}

// Wait for jQuery
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> waitForAjaxResponse() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(final WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                return js.executeScript(
                    "return((window.jQuery == null )||(window.jQuery != null && jQuery.active === 0))").equals(true);
            } catch (final WebDriverException e) {
                LOG.info("Error while waiting for jQuery");
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But all the return statement are true, so i get a `TimeOutException` because JS and jQuery is already done when i switch to the frame but it's false.

The script looks like that :

```
function _optimizeSize() {
    var $popin = $('#iframePopin'),
    // Some var init
    $dialog.transition({top: optimizeTop});
    $popin.transition({height: contentHeight + actionBarHeight + popinPaddingHeight});
    $iFrame.transition({height: contentHeight});
}
```

I looked at some similar case, but i couldn't find any answer to my problem.

Comment: you can easily try to wait and catch the timeout exception

Comment: @pburgr Yes, i already did that, but it's not normal to catch this exception, the problem is to wait the script to be done before switching.